# gradle.properties vs buildscript ext which one is better

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**gradle.properties code snippet**

```
APP_BUILD_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=28
APP_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = 27.0.3

APP_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 16
APP_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 28

supportLibraryVersion = '23.4.0'
playServicesVersion = '9.2.1'
```

**buildscript ext code snippet**

```
ext {
    // sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'

    // dependencies versions
    supportLibraryVersion = '23.4.0'
    playServicesVersion = '9.2.1'
}
```

I've used both in my different projects but anyone knows what is the best difference of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra properties is a special extension of type [`ExtraPropertiesExtension`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension) added with name `ext`.

Properties passed with `-P` command line options or added to `gradle.properties` file are **added to the extra properties extension**.  They’re simply added to one of existing scope